# Meaning of Noam Chomsky's Comment about Trump

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, ambiguity

I am not an American and English is not my language, due to my lack of knowledge in English and cultural difference I am confused about  a comment made by Noam Chomsky, he said that,  ["Trump has been an absolute genius in propaganda", (time-stamp = 1:20:01)](https://www.rollingstone.com/politics/politics-news/noam-chomsky-covid-19-useful-idiots-podcast-970047/).

Now, the word genius means a person who does a lot brain work creatively (good or bad work), but if you follow news or think carefully, you see most of the statement trumps make are not smart, reliable, most of the are false in a comical manner. i would have understand if Steve Banon was called a "genius in propaganda".

This comment does not fit even to sarcasm category, because Trump really has been capable of perusing people,

So, what does N. Chomsky mean? What am I missing here?

Comment: It just means that Trump has a special gift for propaganda. Not that he's an Einstein or a Hawking.

Comment: @Robusto what kind of special gift can you define? he is pretty simple, it just people are in a state where they like person like Trump, one can say he is charismatic but that completly different word that being genius!

Comment: @Andrew - "*what kind of special gift can you define?*" how about "**an absolute genius in propaganda**"? :)

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "Trump really has been capable of perusing people"?

Comment: @Andrew "*the word genius means a person who does a lot brain work creatively*". This is your problem - it is not a good definition of "genius", particularly in its extended sense.

Comment: If you don't like **genius**, you could call Donald a propaganda **maven**, or even **idiot savant**.

Answer (score 5):

The meaning of genius Noam Chomsky is referring to does not seem to be "exceptionally intellectual or creative power or other natural ability" which is "who does a lot of brain work creatively (good or bad work)" but "to be especially skilled at a particular activity" which for this case is propaganda. Same way you'd say, "She has a genius for raising money."

Answer (score 5):

Use this definition ... 
**genius.** A person with exceptional skill in a particular area of activity.
[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/genius)

Answer (score 0):

The answers above are all correct. He is a brilliant propagandist. He is an exceptional propagandist. He has a talent for propaganda.

In that sense, he has a genius for propaganda. He's a propaganda genius.

Chomsky is *not* saying that Trump is a genius. Far from it. He is saying that Trump has a particular skill: propaganda.

You're right, Chomsky is not being sarcastic. But I don't think you mean *perusing*. I think you mean *persuading*.

Comment: Chomsky just meant (as I read) that Trump is highly skilled at propaganda making. At the same time, can one establish that propaganda is such a thing that doesn't need creativity at all?